# Error Executing SSIS package from ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis, ssis-2017

I had a requirement at client side to upgrade SQL server client from 2008 R2 to SQL server 2017. Previously I used SSIS packages build with SQL server 2008 R2, while upgrading the server I am facing connectivity issue when calling the package from asp.net application. Kindly find the below steps undertaken in upgrading the package to work with SQL server 2017.

1. I have opened the package solution file in SSDT 2017 and upgraded it to the latest version.
2. I have changed the native client OLEDB provider to “SQLNCLI11.1” in the connection string.
3. Also, I have added the below mentioned assembly packages in application “ib.config”

   ```
   <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
   <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
   ```

I am getting the following error when tried to call the package from asp.net application.

> Failure To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The error is as indicated

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher

You are attempting to run SSIS packages on a machine that is not licensed for SQL Server. You do not specify all the steps involved with "upgrade SQL server client from 2008 R2 to SQL server 2017" but it seems the server does not have the SQL Server bits on it.

Specifically, the DLLs will be looking for the presence of the SQL Services Integration Services *Service* in the services collection. A box will only have this installed if you have properly installed and licensed the SQL Server software.

Migrating from 2008 R2 to 2017 is quite the jump in versions as well as licensing terms (and expense) as SQL Server generally moved from a per socket to per core licensing. As you're already providing expertise to the client and you've run into this hiccup, I'd strongly encourage you to have a discussion with them to ensure they are properly licensed for their SSIS server (I presume from your description that the asp.net application also has some SQL Server pieces installed on it). Their license authorized reseller (LAR) should be of assistance in wading through the legalese.